# ¿Cómo guardar imagen en la memoria del dispositivo con Xamarin?

Tags: android, c#, imagen, xamarin, bitmap

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.
En esta tengo un pad de firma en la cual el usuario dibuja su firma y luego debo colocarla en un PDF.
El caso es que ya tengo el dibujo de la firma pero cuando quiero guardar la imágen se queda trabado el método...

Este es el código:

```
//Obtengo el directorio de la memoria interna
var directory = new Java.IO.File("/mnt/sdcard", "ImagenesFirmas").ToString();

//Me fijo si no existe la carpeta "ImagenesFirmas" y la creo
if (!Directory.Exists(directory)){
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

//Combino los directorios (la ruta de la carpeta y el nombre de la imagen)
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "FirmaTest.jpg");

if (File.Exists(path)){
    File.Delete(path);
}

//Aquí debería guardar la imagen
using (var bitmap = await FirmaPaciente.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg, Color.Black, Color.White, 3f)) //Aquí es donde se queda trabado el método
using (var dest = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    await bitmap.CopyToAsync(dest);
}
```

¿Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano!!!

---

[Edit]

Suguiendo los comentarios de Andrés, así me quedó el código actualmente.
Cabe destacar también que FirmaPaciente es un [SignaturePadView](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad)

```
var directory = new Java.IO.File("/mnt/sdcard", "InDiSeMED").ToString();
if (!Directory.Exists(directory)){
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "FirmaMatiasMolina.jpg");
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)){
    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
}

Bitmap bitmap = FirmaPaciente.GetImage();
ImageView ImagenFirma = new ImageView(this);
ImagenFirma.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (fOut = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        return await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fOut);
});
```

Comment: Probaste que el Bitmap funciona correctamente (no se muestra transparente) poniendolo en un ImageView?. ¿Cómo creas el signature pad para obtener luego el Bitmap con GetImage();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente dí con la solucion reemplazando est

```
//Aquí debería guardar la imagen
using (var bitmap = await 
FirmaPaciente.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg, Color.Black, Color.White, 3f)) //Aquí es donde se queda trabado el método
using (var dest = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    await bitmap.CopyToAsync(dest);
}
```

Por:

```
//Aquí debería guardar la imagen
var bitmap = await FirmaPaciente.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png, Color.Black, Color.White, 1f);
var dest = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path);
bitmap.CopyToAsync(dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), el `using` obviamente te evita limpiar el objeto manualmente.

En tu codigo, solo reemplazarias guardar la imagen (desde el using):

```
var bitmap = FirmaPaciente.GetImage();

using (FileStream fOut = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)){
      await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fOut);
}
```

En caso de que vayas a repetir la accion muchas veces, Puedes correr todo dentro de un Task y realizar la acción mas tarde con el resultado. Por ejemplo:

```
   await Task.Run(async () => {
          using (FileStream fOut = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                 return await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fOut);

   }).ContinueWith((o) => {
         if(o.Result)
            // Lanza un toast diciendo que se guardo bien
         else
            // Lanza un toast diciendo que hubo un error
   });
```

Ten en cuenta que el `FileMode.Create` te lanzara una excepción si el archivo existe, por lo que debes asegurarte que 100% el archivo no existe. Puedes utilizar `FileMode.CreateNew` que lo que hará es sobreescribirlo en caso de que exista.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Andres! El primer problema que surge es que bitmap es de tipo `Stream` entonces al querer usar el `FileStream` me dió error de que no tiene un metodo `CompressAsync`. Lo que hice fue usar `Bitmap bitmap = FirmaPaciente.GetImage();` y ese error dejó de aparecer, ahora el problema que tengo es que no veo la imágen en el dispositivo, pero en el debug veo que pasa por todas las sentencias

Comment: Perdon, con que no veo la imágen me refiero a que está en blanco

Comment: @Matias mira a ver si el bitmap se esta descargando bien. Intenta setearlo en un `ImageView` antes de guardarlo. Luego de que se guarde, intenta cargarlo como un File con el path en el `ImageView` nuevamente. Esta raro que dices que se vea en Blanco.

Comment: Ahí edité la publicación para que veas como me quedó y me puedas decir si hice algo mal... soy nuevo programando en C# y hay varias cosas que no entiendo

Comment: @Matias no. Intenta crear aunque sea temporalmente un ImageView en el axml. Si lo haces asi dinamicamente. Tendrias que asignarle todas sus propiedades y asignarlo a un contenedor. Esa clase donde estas haciendo esas operaciones de Bitmaps, es un Fragment, un Activity o algo parecido?. Si ese es el caso, tienes que buscar el Layout que carga dicha pantalla y agregar un ImageView en el axml.

Comment: Pude hacerlo con otra variación del código que puse inicialmente... igualmente marco como útil tu respuesta y te agradezco por la paciencia y tu ayuda!

Comment: @Matias excelente. Puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada (debajo del contador de votos) para que la pregunta no quede abierta. Saludos.